# Simple real-time plotting using real-time plot data

Tags: c++, linux, plot

This question is in ref. to one of my earlier posts here:
[Using KoolPlot On Linux (Linux Mint 10)? Or Is it for MingW Only..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478466/using-koolplot-on-linux-linux-mint-10-or-is-it-for-mingw-only)

I am not able to decide which library should I really go with  for plotting a real-time statistics data graph which should use real time incoming data streams in C++ ?

I google'd and found these:

> gnuplot (confused about this one.. realtime data plot using real-time data feed..? using stdin / pipes? how?)
>
> koolplot (wish it was for linux too..am not able to find graphics.h; is it even present in ~nux'es..? )
>
> SIGL (http://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/plot/)
> (commercial but does provides a evaluation yet download able copy of its commercial code)

Well the first question..why I am not just trying anyone of them out.. is:
I hate to mess up with my system :( I would not like to do it now.. since I am in the middle of my engineeering project

So, could somebody can just provide me with an example of which library and how can i use it to work..to plot data vars of my c++ project? I just need to plot a simple 2-d graph of the network performance statistics of my project so I would not go with for picking up data values from a stored file..so would like to do it in real-time only (still preferred) :)

Comment: Duplicates at least back to http://stackoverflow.com/q/884849/2509.

Comment: hmm.. 8) i think I landed on the right spot.. Thanks dmckee! but umm..still I am not able to get my hands on the perfect fit for "real-time" data plotter; i want the plots to be plotted side by side as my program runs and not by storing thee values first & then plotting them back. Secondly i need it first for "Linux" environment and not for win32 (as for win32 the simplest one I could check out is koolplot).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Qt and [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/).  I am currently using it in a real-time spectral display and raster application and it performs quite well, even with huge amounts of streaming data.  It is written in a very extensible way so you can customize almost anything if you want to put in the work.  Check out the examples included with the download to see all the possibilities, including several real-time examples.

You will have to learn some Qt most likely, but it is not too bad if you have C++ experience and it is documented very well.

Comment: hey..looks good.. but still I am not in a situation to go out of schedule..to learn QT :( isn't there any more of simple graph plot tools so that I can plot a simple graph directly from my c++ code? by just importing one/two .h header files and/or a library file?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Qwt.

Comment: @echo9 These are excellent, introductory C++ Qt tutorials, 23:47:37 total time!

[**C++ Qt Programming
by Bryan Cairns**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63). You could play them back at 2× on YouTube, just to get through them faster.

Answer (score 0):

This should work well:

## **[feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot)**

> Tool to plot realtime and stored data from the commandline, using gnuplot. This is the repo for 'feedgnuplot' on CPAN http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feedgnuplot